# Appending HTML Element's value in PHP page link

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an HTML file as follows:

```
<html>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <section>
      <article id="news-card">
        <div id='identity'>011</div>
        <h1>HEADLINE</h1>
        <p>AUTHOR</p>
        <a href='#' class='readmore'>Read more</a>
        <form action='postnews.php' method='post'>
          <input type='checkbox' name='bookmark'>Bookmark?</input>
        </form>
      </article>
      <section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and here's the PHP file:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "News-Articles";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$_bookmark = isset($_POST["bookmark"]) ? 'Y' : 'N';
$sql =     "INSERT INTO stats (iid, bookmark, readmore, counter)
           VALUES ('$_iid', '$_bookmark', NULL, NULL)
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
           bookmark = '$_bookmark';"
mysqli_query($conn, $update);
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I want to include the value of the element with id = 'identity' into the form's action attribute. Something like this:

```
<form action = "postnews.php?iid=getElementById(identity).innerHTML">
```

So, in the PHP file, I can `$_GET["iid"]` to insert the value of bookmark for that particular iid. How can I approach the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add iid=value to the form's action on submit.  I put in a check for ? so if the action already has a query string it just appends iid to it.

```js
var theForm = document.getElementById('bookmark-form');
theForm.addEventListener('submit', changeAction, false);

function changeAction(event)
{
  event = event || window.event;

  var form = event.target;
  var idDiv = document.getElementById('identity');
  var idToAdd = idDiv.innerHTML;
  var action = form.action;

  if (action.indexOf('?') === -1) {
    form.action = action + '?iid=' + idToAdd;
  } else {
    form.action = action + '&iid=' + idToAdd;
  }

  event.preventDefault();

  console.log(form.action);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <section>
      <article id="news-card">
        <div id='identity'>011</div>
        <h1>HEADLINE</h1>
        <p>AUTHOR</p>
        <a href='#' class='readmore'>Read more</a>
        <form action='postnews.php' method='post' id="bookmark-form">
          <input type='checkbox' name='bookmark'>Bookmark?</input>
          <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
        </form>
      </article>
      <section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could include a hidden input field.

```
<input type='hidden' name='iid' value="<?php echo $iid; ?>" >
```

This will make it available in your $_POST variable e.g. `$_POST['iid']`

Comment: This doesn't work. For the above code, I want the value '011' (that's the inner HTML of id ='identity') to be passed in the PHP file as postnews.php?iid='011' when the form is submitted.

Comment: If you want to get the innter HTML of an element that's not an input field within your form, you will need to look at using ajax to post your form. Have a look at https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ 

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});

populate `data` with your innerHtml values and form data

Comment: It works normally but Himanshu Ahuja wants to get the id from action. So post action must be changed with js or jquery as document.postNewsForm.action = y; So you have to try my codes in answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <section>
            <article id="news-card">
                <div id='identity'>011</div>
                <h1>HEADLINE</h1>
                <p>AUTHOR</p>
                <a href='#' class='readmore'>Read more</a>
                <form action='' method='post' id='postNewsForm'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='bookmark'>Bookmark?</input>
                </form>
            </article>
        </section>
    </div>

    <script>
       var x = document.getElementById("identity").innerHTML;
       var y = "postnews.php?iid=" + x;     
       document.postNewsForm.action = y;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```